# Maximize sums of products via permutation

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $A = [a_0, a_2, ..., a_{n-1}]$ and $B = [b_0, b_1, ..., b_{n-1}]$ be two array of positive real numbers. Find a permutation $\pi$ of $A$ which maximizes the following sum

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}a_{\pi(i)}a_{\pi(i+1)}b_i$$

where the indices are taken modulo $n$.

It is important to note that $B$ is fixed and $A$ can be permuted. If it were the other way around, the maximum can be achieved by pairing the largest $a_ia_{i+1}$ with the largest $b_j$, the second largest $a_{i}a_{i+1}$ with with the second largest $b_j$, and so on.